# Функции с разным количеством параметров в словаре Python

Tags: python, словари, dict

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется словарь типа {'str': def} Каждая функция принимает разное количество параметров. Как можно реализовать корректный вызов функции в моем цикле?

```
def create_account(name):
    if name not in clients.keys():
        clients[name] = 0

def withdraw(name, sum):
    create_account(name)
    clients[name] -= int(sum)

def transfer(name1, name2, sum):
    create_account(name1)
    create_account(name2)
    clients[name1] -= int(sum)
    clients[name2] += int(sum)

def income(p):
    for client in clients:
        if clients[client] > 0:
            clients[client] *= 1 + p / 100
            clients[client] = int(clients[client])

input_list = [['DEPOSIT', 'Ivanov', '100'], ['INCOME', '5'], 
['BALANCE', 'Ivanov'], ['TRANSFER', 'Ivanov', 'Petrov', '50'], 
['WITHDRAW', 'Petrov', '100'], ['BALANCE', 'Petrov'], ['BALANCE', 'Sidorov']]

operations_dict = {'DEPOSIT': deposit,
                   'WITHDRAW': withdraw,
                   'BALANCE': balance,
                   'TRANSFER': transfer,
                   'INCOME': income}

for request in input_list:
    if request[0] in operations_dict:
        operations_dict[request[0]]()
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, и `request` у вас содержит нулевым элементом название функции, а остальными элементыми - аргументы, которые нужно передать, то можно использовать синтаксис распаковки:

```
for request in input_list:
    func_code = request[0]
    func_args = request[1:]
    if func_code in operations_dict: 
        operations_dict[func_code](*func_args)  # распаковываем аргументы из списка
```

Comment: Или так: `func_code, *func_args = request`

Comment: Спасибо, работает!